# What is git checkout -b <branchname> for?

Tags: git

What is `git checkout -b <branchname>` for ?

I mean, you can create a branch by doing `git branch <branchname>`

but, what it does `git checkout -b <branchname>` specifically ?

Comment: A quick quote from the documentation of [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout): *"Specifying `-b` causes a new branch to be created as if [`git-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) were called and then checked out."*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That means you do two things:

1. Create a new branch `<branchname>`
2. Checkout the new branch `<branchname>`

It's simply shorthand for creating a new branch and then directly checking it out.

```
$ git checkout -b new-feature
```

Is shorthand for and the equivalent of:

```
$ git branch new-feature
$ git checkout new-feature
```

For reference, please see the [documentation on git-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer You're quite welcome!